# How do I ensure that whichever thread that passes over a given breakpoint doesn't skip?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Using ASP.NET and Entity Framework Core I can't break the execution of the method in my controller that is not properly responding to the client application.

I set a breakpoint for a method in my controller but I'm worried that because the method is possibly being executed by a thread which I believe to be in a separate process, that I will need some other way of breaking it.

How do I ensure that a breakpoint is traversed, or if the breakpoint is not traversed, how do I ensure that the program breaks at the exception that prevented the execution from reaching the breakpoint?

Comment: *"I can't set a breakpoint for my controller methods because they get executed by a thread."* Huh? This doesn't make a lot of sense - can you explain exactly what you're doing and what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a breakpoint to a method should stop execution regardless of the thread executing that method. There's nothing in Visual Studio's debugger that can only break on the "main" thread, which isn't really a thing in server-side code that doesn't have a "foreground/UI" thread vs "background" threads. Threadpool threads are just regular threads that are managed by a threadpool.

If your breakpoints are being skipped, you need to find the reason for it.

- Is it possible you're not attached to the right process?
- Is it possible you have no debugging symbols loaded in the debugging session?
- Maybe your local code is different than the one compiled, leading VS to disable the breakpoints automatically?

Try hovering over the breakpoint in VS to see if there's an error message shown, and redirect your efforts away from the issue of "threads" to finding the actual culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm running a server and my controller code seems to be executing in a thread. I see you were saying it should break the execution regardless of which thread is executing, but is that true for threads that are not a part of the mains process?

Comment: I'm worried that since I'm running ASP and Entity Framework Core that maybe a separate process is running and so not a part of the currently executing process or any of it's child threads.

Comment: Execution does not break and the breakpoint shows no error, yet the code still executes returning a 500 response to the client, which could be response timeout though I'm not sure that it would be that because I would still be able to step on VS

Comment: Options include enabling "break on all exceptions" to catch even exceptions that are handled, increasing logging on the server, or finding where to add inspectors during the ASP.NET pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I checked the CLR exceptions in the Exceptions settings and now I get redirected to an exception, it turns out it was unable to resolve my service interface before execution ever got to the breakpoint